# use of present simple vs present continuous

Tags: present-tense

Which of these is correct ?

"The day of my visit approaches"

"The day of my visit is approaching"

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct. Idiomatically the continuous form is used in circumstances where there is no relative clause. *His great opportunity is approaching*

However it would be idiomatic to say *The day approaches when I shall have the opportunity to do something useful*.

Or *The day approaches all too quickly when I shall have to make a decision*.